# Module is not loaded by Prism framework if a type from the same module is used explicitly

Tags: wpf, prism, prism-5

We have a WPF application using prism 5 framework.
Modules are loaded using DirectoryModuleCatalog. At the same time if I refer one of the modules in the start up project where bootstrapper is located and use a type from it, that module is skipped from loading.

Looks like the prism framework is skipping it as it is already loaded in AppDomain.

Is there any way to load the module albeit a type from it is referred in the startup project?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are only referencing the Module and not actually adding the module to your module catalog. Either that doesn't need to be a module, or you need to create an aggregate module catalog that you can use to add multiple different catalogs.

Here is an example: http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V5/Quickstarts/Modularity/Desktop/ModularityWithUnity/ModularityWithUnity.Desktop/AggregateModuleCatalog.cs

Also, not sure why you are using Prism 5 as that is way out of date an no longer supported.  You should be using Prism 6.3.

Comment: The modules are loading using DirectoryModuleCatalog. So all the modules in the folder are loaded automatically. The one particular module is not loading because I am referring a type from it directly.

Comment: Do I still need to use AggregateModuleCatalog?

Comment: Same Problem here, is there any solution ? even the AggregateModuleCatalog is not clear