# Prism doesn't load all my module in my DirectoryCatalog folder

Tags: c#, .net, module, prism

I've got a prism application(With unity bootstrapper), which is configured to load modules with a DirectoryCatalog from a folder called "Services".

In this folder, I've two DLL, with the same project settings(framework settings), both having a class derivating from `IModule`(No attributes in both projects).

For some reason, the application goes into one project module's constructor but not in the other one.

I'm trying to figure out what I could have missed. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the other module is being skipped from loading. Try explicitly loading the module just to check whats actually going on. Also refer to the following similar questions.

[On Demand Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920391/prism-v4-loading-modules-on-demand-with-directorymodulecatalog)

[Skipped loading issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792023/module-is-not-loaded-by-prism-framework-if-a-type-from-the-same-module-is-used-e)

Comment: What do you mean by "Explicitely loading" ?

Comment: I meant, loading the modules on demand by calling the "LoadModule" method. Also check out the official documentation [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)